# Default values of props in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

How can I define default values in ReactJS?

```
var Header = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
      return (
         <h1>{this.props.title} if not defined insert "Title"</h1>
      )
    }
});
```

---

> I extremely increased my React skill and as of 2018 this example (I
>   wrote at the question body) is outdated. You should do it like
>   **@VladyVeselinov** shown at the picture using ES6 classes and babel
>   transforms like babel-class-properties that allow you to make static
>   fields for your components

Comment: A cleaner way of writing components may be using ES6? http://i.imgur.com/7EHQRdl.png

Comment: I extremely increased my `React` skill and as of 2018 this example (I wrote at the question body) is outdated. You should do it like @VladyVeselinov shown at the picture using ES6 classes and babel transforms like `babel-class-properties` that allow you to make `static` fields for your components

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since your example uses the createClass version of creating a component, you can use the getDefaultProps function.

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-without-es6.html#declaring-prop-types-and-default-props

```
 getDefaultProps: function() {
    return {
      title: 'Title'
    };
  }
```